# Why we should use PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have just started to learn HTML, JavaScript and PHP. After studying little, I sometimes think to myself, "why we need PHP"? Whatever we can do using PHP, can be done using Javascript(I think that but I am a noob to this). So why do we use PHP? Can anybody explain to me its use?( I apologize in advance if the question is totally foolish and the answer is very obvious - but as I said, I am noob to web).

Comment: Now before people continue to falsely state that JavaScript runs on the clientside only, some educational material: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript

Comment: Javascript was created to manipulate the Html DOM (Document Object Model), the DOM is created after the browser has parsed the HTML.

Comment: Serverside Javascript was first released in 1994 (soon after releasing JavaScript for browsers)... I don't think the intension of js wasn't just clientside execution.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

PHP is a server-side scripting language. JavaScript is run client-side.

You can for example not do anything database related in JavaScript. Even *if* there where database libraries written for JavaScript they would be of no use because your server cannot trust database queries done by the client. For example, you cannot delete forum posts client-side because then anybody would be able to delete those posts under the disguise of an administrator.

PHP can do **a lot** that JS cannot do. Image resizing, saving files on the server, database queries, e-mailing, PDF generation, secure login systems, RSS parsing, SOAP calls to web services, anything where you cannot trust the client (because the user can change JS code as they want, and there's no way for you to control that).

They are two entirely different languages, made for different needs.

There are however a few JS servers, which run JavaScript code server-side. [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org) is one example of such a system. Then you don't need to learn a new language, but you still need to differentiate what you do in the client from what you do on the server-side.

Comment: There are http://taffydb.com/ and http://www.mongodb.org/ to name a few. So, there *ARE* database libraries written for JavaScript =) JS could not handle FS and OS operations only (afaik) =) Note: PHP dies - there are lots of great replacements, which are more powerful, safe, simple, reusable etc than PHP (e.g. Rails, Django...) =)

Comment: @Ramon Although they're great replacements for PHP for sure =)

Comment: What you've said is not actually correct. You can create a user like 'guest_user' in a database and give him only select privileges on certain tables, so it will not have access to every table in your database nor will he be able to edit/update tables. DBMS have very good user access control and there is no need for php for that reason.

Comment: Also you can do any kind of request that you can do with curl from javascript, so there is no need for php if you want to do that.

Comment: Image resizing is also doable from javascript. The only thing (I think) is not possible from the list you compiled is file upload from javascript. Everything else is possible. So for a new guy, I would suggest to focus on learning javascript, because you can cover almost everything with one language, and those few things that you can't you can use node.js or similar solutions.

Comment: It's much better to be great in one language than to spread your self across few languages but not being good at them. Make a good choice and then go deep with it, learn everything you can.

Comment: PHP is needed for performance, because if you have memcached and a database, and let's say you make your whole site in javascript. If you want to get some data you would first need to check if it's cached in memcached and if not then make another request to fetch that from the database. If the end user is far far away in another part of the world that communication would be slow, while if you have apache+php memcached and database closely together they can communicate much faster between themselves and then return result to the end user.

Comment: So everything would be served in one request from the end user, which is faster than making several requests from the end user and then waiting for the response from memcached and then the database etc.

Comment: I think you contradicted your statement with your last paragraph. Of course we know it php is server side and javascript was born client side, however, just like you stated, it is now going cross platform. So in that sense, JS could eventually over-throw php if it grows in server side functionality.

Comment: Idealcastle, you do realize I posted this answer six years ago? NodeJS was little more than a hack back then. Most of the stuff in my answer (apart from database queries) can now be done on either the client or server side due to advances in the browser too.

Comment: Why would you use a html/xml/javascript -style laungage for handling the server though. I thought these laungages was meant for interaction over the internet (more or less). Would it not make more sense to use a language like java or C# to handle the server. Setting up a server is not internet interaction - it is something that you do locally (on some sort of computer I guess). Is php for people that do not want to set up servers with java/c#, as they are so different from html/xml/javascript and that already happen to possess great knowledge of html/xml/javascript?

Answer (score 19):

The main difference here is **not** PHP vs. JavaScript. It's **Client vs. Server**. You can't do server stuff on the client, and you can't do all the Client stuff on the Server.

JavaScript is an **embeddable** scripting language, so it can run in a Browser, but it can **just as well** run on a Server.

So all you need is to run it on a Server and there's no more need for PHP, how do we do that?
**[Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info)**

Saying that JavaScript is **client-side** these days, is like saying that Lua is only uses for **scripting games**.

Answer (score 8):

PHP is designed as server-side scripting language, JS for client-side.
Sure, you can use JS for server-side as well if you really wanted to. You can also learn German rather then Dutch if you're moving to the Netherlands since quite a lot of people speak it, its just not the most efficient way of communicating. Sure, its easier to use a single language rather then having to learn both PHP and JS. Same is true for German, which is spoken by more people in the world, but when staying in the Netherlands for a long time it pays off to know the Dutch language. If you are planning to only make a single website, then sticking to JS alone might be the best thing to do. If on the other hand you are planning to be a serious web developer, its worthwhile to know PHP eventually anyway. Learning both is time well spent I say.

Answer (score 7):

Despite the fact that PHP is commonly written in-line in the same files as HTML and Javascript, PHP is a server side language.  Javascript is a client-side language.

For a self-described "noob", I can think of no better place to start your education than to understand the difference between code that runs on the server and on the client.

Comment: +1 Aye, a fundamental point to understand.  A reasonably modern problem as many new programmers come upon client-server architectures as their first port of call.  When I was learning they were uncommon and advanced, many years of learning went on in a single-user arena before exposing ourselves to that.

Comment: I disagree with "PHP is commonly written in-line in the same files as HTML". That may have been it's original use case, but professional PHP programmers use abstractions and frameworks (just like in other languages) that separate content from structure, controller from view. It was true in 2010 when this was answered, and it's still true now.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest difference is that PHP runs on the server while JavaScript runs on the client.

Think of the server and client as two people, say Alice and Bob, and consider the following two scenarios:

- Alice bakes a cake and sends it to Bob. This is like **server-side processing** using PHP. Bob just gets the cake and has no idea who baked it or how. Similarly, in your browser, all you see is the final output generated by PHP, you don't see the "source code".
- Alice sends the ingredients and recipe to Bob, and Bob bakes the cake at his house. This is like **client-side processing** using JavaScript. Your browser gets the JavaScript source code from the server and executes it on your computer.

Now you get the same end-result in both cases, however this may not always be the case:

- **Security:** Alice may not want Bob to know her secret recipe, so she always bakes the cake and sends it. This is like using PHP to hide the details of what happens on the server.
- **Resources:** Bob may not have the necessary tools (eg. an oven) to bake the cake, so Alice does it for him. This is like using PHP to connect to a database because JavaScript does not have access to the database server.

Answer (score 2):

> Whatever we can do by PHP, can be done using Javascript(I think that but I am a noob to this).

No this is not true. One thing you cannot do with javascript is to connect to a SQL database on your server which is kind of common task in web development.

Comment: OFFF, I have studied this in javascript, then to I forgot.So database connectivity is the major reason to use PHP, or there are more?

Comment: @r.s. mahanti: Well, they're totally different, to be honest. Javascript is a client language, PHP is a server language. They're not meant to do the same task.

Comment: There are also other reasons like storing data on the client side is not very secure as everyone will be able to see it, while if you used a server side storage you would be able to fetch data which is only supposed to be seen by the current user.

Answer (score 1):

PHP and JavaScript are both just languages. As mentioned by the other answers, they are **commonly used** for server-side and client-side scripting respectively.

However, there's a twist, which should be mentioned. JavaScript can actually be used server-side as well. There are server runtime environments such as [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) that allow you do that, and potentially allow you to get away with one less programming language to use.

The client-side limitation remains the same, however. That is because browsers typically only implement a JavaScript runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not being able to access a database, you wouldn't *want* to do everything client-side with JavaScript. It would be too much processing for the client; especially those trying to run your site on older computers or on mobile devices. Using PHP, you can pre-compute the HTML before sending it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a **client-side** scripting language. That is, it executes in the client (web browser in this instance) and has access to resources on the client computer (such as the actual keyboard and mouse inputs, etc.). PHP is a **server-side** scripting language. That is, it executes on the web server, and has access to the resources available on the web server computer.

Other combinations are possible:

- Some web browsers support client-side scripting in languages other than JavaScript. (For instance, Internet Explorer allows VBScript.) But JavaScript (or, more formally, ECMA-262 ECMAScript) is the only client-side scripting language supported out of the box on all modern web browsers.
- It's possible to use PHP with clients that aren't web browsers. For example, a PHP script can produce XML instead of HTML, and that XML could be read by an RSS reader, for instance.
- Depending on your web server configuration, there are many more choices for server-side development than just PHP. These range from the "enterprisey" solutions like Java EE and ASP.NET to lightweight languages like PHP and Perl, and everything in between.

Answer (score 0):

Both PHP and javascript are scripting languages. But php is bound to the server side and javascript is bound to the client side. A user need not do anything if he/she wants to use a PHP site because the server hosting the php application puts up with the computing involved in it. As far as the user is concerned it's just plain HTML.

But in case of Javascript the computation that is requried to process the javascript requests is handled by the user's own processor, plus there is another issue of having enabled javascript in that particular person's browser. With php there is no such issue. So php is better. I hope I helped. Good luck...